# Contact form not working from free template

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I got this free template but the contact form is not working at all. It says the message was sent but I don't receive any email. The form looks really nice that's why I don't want to change it but it's not working. The developer does not provide technical help for free templates. Please help me and thank you in advance!

HTML

```
        <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" role="form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                        <div class="form_status" style="display: none;"><p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We'll get back to you shortly.</p></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
                        </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'nikita_lim@rocketmail.com';//replace with your email

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
```

JS

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        url: '../sendemail.php',
        //type : $(this).attr('method'),
        //data : $(this).serialize(),

        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: your mail headers are failing you. RTM again; you missed something. Edit: Never mind, here `implode("\r\n", $headers)` there, solved. As per the Ffffffffabulous manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 2):

Posting as a community wiki.

Your mail headers are failing you.

Therefore, add `implode("\r\n", $headers)` as per what the manual states:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";
$headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Comment: @Nnn check for errors then http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and look at your console.

Comment: Hi fried. I value your opinion a lot and was wondering if you could let me know if this particular question in your opinion is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451962/query-string-protection-against-sql-injection-and-xss

Comment: @Webeng It's a 50% good close. I don't think it was a bad close. However, that type of question has been asked quite a few times and including the XSS injection stuff. So, it's best to use a prepared statement and for the XSS issue; there is already quite a few Q&A's on Stack and other parts of the Web.